# cakePHP - form - if checkbox is selected show and validate another field

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, checkbox, dependencies

Is it possible to let cakePHP handle a dependency of input field?

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('foo');
echo $this->Form->input('bar'); //is hidden initially
```

And only show and validate bar if foo is checked?

Comment: ok so I can't define in the Model?

Comment: No, not in real time anyway. You just need 3 lines of jQuery though. not that big of a deal.

Comment: Alright, jquery I know how to handle!

Comment: You should ensure the validation is still handled server-side in case someone attempts to use your form with JS switched off, even if you validate using JS too.

Answer (score 3):

The necessary jQuery (you will need to update the classes for your code as you haven't actually put the real names). Initially you'll want to hide bar with CSS.

```
(function(){

    $('#foo').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#bar').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is using javascript, remember that CakePHP just generate the PHP Code for the side server

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#MyModelFoo').change(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#MyModelBar').fadeIn();
    }
});
</script>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('MyModel');
echo $this->Form->checkbox('foo');
echo $this->Form->input('bar'); //is hidden initially
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it it but for that you need to use client side programming as php can't do such show hide..j Query is the best...in cakephp there is already a feature to check such dependency and if i am not wrong it's called observField as cakephp use prototype js by default.

[**for more**](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/AJAX.html#observefield)

Comment: Isn't observeField old? Shouldn't I use jsHelper instead?

Comment: you can, i just gave hint about what you can do..i also told you to use jquery so that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript. You can’t hide/show input fields dynamically with a server-side programming language, which CakePHP is written with.

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted the jQuery necessary to show/hide the field, here's how you validate it in CakePHP:

In AppModel:

```
public function requiredIfChecked($check, $associatedField) {

    $value = array_pop($check);

    if ($this->data[$this->alias][$associatedField] && empty($value)) {

        return false;

    }
    else {

        return true;

    }

}
```

In your validation array:

```
public $validate = array( 
    'bar'=>array(
        'required_if_checked'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('requiredIfChecked', 'foo'),
            'message'=>'cannot be blank if foo is checked'
        )
    )
);
```