# CakePHP 2.4.4 if checkbox is selected show and validate another field

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

My question is similar to: [cakePHP - form - if checkbox is selected show and validate another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851267/cakephp-form-if-checkbox-is-selected-show-and-validate-another-field).
I have a set of fields in a form:

```
/* view */
echo $this->Form->input('immagine', array('type' => 'checkbox'));
echo $this->Form->input('url');
```

and the model, with the validation rules:

```
/* model */
class Question extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
            'url' => array(
                'required_if_checked'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('requiredIfChecked', 'immagine'),
                    'message'=>'cannot be blank if foo is checked',
                )
            )
        );
    public function requiredIfChecked($check, $associatedField) {
        $value = array_pop($check);
        if ($this->data[$this->alias][$associatedField] && empty($value)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

On the page, the url field is marked as required either the checkbox is ticked or not.
I've tried adding

```
'required' => false,
'allowEmpty' => true
```

in the model, but that just does what it says, ignoring the validation rules.

I want the 'url' field to be validated ONLY if the 'immagine' checkbox is ticked.
Thank you all for help.

Comment: Ignoring the HTML markup output to the view, is your validation rule working as expected?

Comment: No, the validation rule is not working, as it's defined in the model.

Comment: Sorted it out: adding echo $this->Form->create('Question', array('novalidate' => true)); in the view solves it. The form is validated correctly.